# How do I set Silverlight to auto-update on OS X?

Tags: macos, silverlight

Is there a way to have Silverlight automatically install updates without user interaction?

I'm running Boxee on a Mac Mini, and I make heavy use of the Netflix app.  However, when I start watching a Netflix movie or TV show, Silverlight often tells me "There is an update to Silverlight available, do you want to install it?"  I have to start up Screen Sharing or plug in a mouse to click "OK" and continue.  I'd rather just update Silverlight automatically without user interaction.

**Update:** I do not use this solution for Netflix anymore - there are native apps on my iPhone, iPad, Apple TV, and even built into my Samsung TV, which make the Silverlight plugin obsolete.  My best guess is that there are security reasons why automated installs are not allowed, and won't be added as a feature.  I'm accepting the best "Turn off auto-updates" as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mac OS X, launch the alias: `/Applications/Microsoft Silverlight` (the app).  You should see the Updates choices. Choose "Never check for updates". If you don't find the alias in `/Applications`, you should find the app in `/Library/Internet Plug-ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/Resources/Silverlight Preferences.app`, which means you might have to right-click on the plugin to get into the Contents, etc.

For Windows, I recommend navigating:  Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Silverlight -> Microsoft Silverlight (the app), and launch it. Choose the "Updates" tab, and choose "Never check for updates".

Comment: I think your instructions are the opposite of what the question asks for.  The question asks about installing updates automatically.  Your answer is about not checking for updates.

Comment: Yes, the opposite, but I'm still up-voting because it is a multi-platform, detailed answer to "how do I stop getting annoyed by the Silverlight update dialog"? implied question.

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping for the same thing but since it IS a Microsoft product, of course it doesn't have this option and pops up its message at the most inopportune time possible, in the worst way (a yes/no dialog box). It doesn't even have an option to start an update later, when you're not just starting to watch a movie.

What it does have is in the preferences ( /Applications/Microsoft Silverlight ) you can turn off the message by setting it to not check for updates. The down side is it's then up to you to manually check and download updates.